# DRF with TokenAuthentication - Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed a project on Elastic Beanstalk and I can't figure out why **Django Rest Framework** returns this response:

```
Authentication credentials were not provided.
```

when I go to `../api/article`

I'm sending header - Authorization: Token

```
curl -X GET http://environment.eba-etpcqsqk.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/article/ -H 'Authorization: Token MYTOKEN'

{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Views:

```
class ArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filterset_class = ArticleFilter

    # user must be either logged in or must provide AUTH TOKEN
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

I've `DEBUG=True` and it works on the development server. Do you know where is the problem? Maybe EBS doesn't forward Headers?

Comment: I bet you have to explitily allow it to ... I know i had to do that with the cloudfront stuff ... aws is awesome and all ... but getting it setup can be a real pain in the ass

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, that was the problem. Thanks